# добавить такой http заголовок к запросу для получения XML в HttpURLConnection. Спасибо

Tags: android, xmlparser

Пытаюсь разобрать XML с сайта. 
Для получения ответа нужно добавить  http заголовок к запросу типа

```
X-A: 973723232323232323
```

Вот при таком варианте XML не получаю, что не так ?

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-A", "97377d");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Iniciar la petición
    conn.connect();
    return conn.getInputStream();
```

ТАк выкидывает Internal Server error

Причем если в качестве сайта ставлю сайт который не просит теги то весь код работает(((

Comment: Internal Server error значит только то, что надо спросить разработчиков сервера :)

Comment: Спрошу для себя, Почему тогда если делаю такой запрос с хэдером вот тут https://hurl.quickblox.com/ то все работает в смысле сервер отдает xml?  От этого я и исходил что проблема в заголовке, но при подмене сайта на другой все опять же фурычит(

Comment: А что Вы от нас-то хотите? У Вас проблема с конкретным сервером, о котором мы ничего не знаем, адрес хоть приложите.